# How to set the meta robots NOINDEX tag to header of a specific category page?

Tags: magento2, no-index, crawler

I need to insert `<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>` in a specific category page of our Magento site. Could you please share an example of how to do it? I don't want to use any module for this. I want the page to appear in the site menu and be available to users. I just don’t want it crawled. [Here](https://www.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/light-bulbs-and-parts.html) is page I'm talking about.

Comment: You should create "Custom Layout Update" xml file.

Bcz magento2.4 does not provide Layout update xml in admin category design.

Comment: create "catalog_category_view_selectable_<Category ID>_<Layout Update Name>.xml" in theme and set there.

Comment: S.P, what should I put in here <Layout Update Name>? and which directory should this file go in?

Comment: you can set any name there. Ex catalog_category_view_selectable_182_ROBOTCHANGE.

Comment: here 182 is category id. and ROBOTCHANGE Would be display in category DESIGN -> CUSTOM LAYOUT UPDAT Field.

Comment: you can set this file in your theme or module.

FOR Module : app/code/{{module}}/{{modulename}}/view/frontend/layout/

or 
Theme : app/design/frontend/{{theme}}/{{themename}}/Magento_Catalog/layout/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would go by Module way. I believe in this XML file, I should insert this line <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: is your xml file loaded on category - > custom layut update field?

Comment: change my udpated anser. may be it would help for set your custom layut in category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can Change Category Layout for Specific Category.

Suppose your categor id is 182. and you wish to your category custom layout name is CHANGEROBOT.
`catalog_category_view_selectable_182_CHANGEROBOT.xml`

create category custom layout file in theme or module.

`app/code/{{module}}/{{modulename}}/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view_selectable_{{categoryid}}_{{customlayoutname}}.xml`

or

`app/design/frontend/{{theme}}/{{themename}}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view_selectable_{{categoryid}}_{{customlayoutname}}.xml`

set your metadata there.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
</head>
```

your customlayout would be load on cateogy custom layout update field.

CATALOG > CATEGORY > DESIGN > CUSTOM LAYOUT UPDATE (set new layout).

clean cache and check in your category page.

you can get better idea from reference : https://www.magevision.com/blog/post/change-category-layout-for-specific-category-magento-2